# Changing Datelist order

Tags: date-and-time

Im wondering how can I formulate a function which receives input in the string format `"day.month.year hours: minutes: seconds"` (for example, `"10.12.2012 3:25:05"`) and returns the time in the form of `{year, month, day, hour, min, sec}`.

I guess a start is

```
 datelist[{"10.12.2012 03:25:05", {"Day", "Month", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}}]
```

but how do I continue?

Comment: Like this `DateList[{"10.12.2012 03:25:05", {"Day", ".", "Month", ".", "Year", 
   " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Apart from the incorrect capitalization of the function name your suggested input

```
DateList[{"10.12.2012 03:25:05", {"Day", "Month", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}}]
```

> {2012, 12, 10, 3, 25, 5.}

seems to do exactly what you want.

Rolling that into a function is rather trivial:

```
ClearAll[dateConvert]
dateConvert[date_String] := 
        DateList[{date, {"Day", "Month", "Year", "Hour", "Minute",   "Second"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time users: b.gatessucks and Sjoerd C. de Vries. Problem is solved. Thanks